# Как полчить массив по его значению в двумерном масиве?

Tags: php

вот массив

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(6) { 
        ["class"]=> string(19) "\common\models\Gods" 
        ["label"]=> string(27) "выбирите Товар" 
        ["title"]=> string(5) "title" } 
    [1]=> array(7) { 
        ["class"]=> string(23) "\common\models\Category" 
        ["title"]=> string(4) "name" 
        ["id"]=> string(2) "id" 
    } 
}
```

я получаю вот такое значение `"\common\models\Category"` ключа `["class"]` но мне надо получить весь подмассив то есть

```
[1]=> array(7) { 
        ["class"]=> string(23) "\common\models\Category" 
        ["title"]=> string(4) "name" 
        ["id"]=> string(2) "id" 
    }
```

не подскажите  как

Comment: Конечно не по теме, но... ты активный участник, уже давно разрабатываешь что-то, задаешь вопросы (250 штук), узнаешь что-то...неужели ты до сих пор не научился банально придумать цикл и сравнить значение в нем? Вот серьезно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вот веришь не разу так не делал .

Comment: Не далал что? Не ознакамливался с основами PHP и подразделом "циклы"? или не работал c `foreach` и `if` (что [явно не так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a13993%20foreach)) или не пользовался логикой?...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский пока не понимаю логику как, подскажи что надо узнать и куда сунуть. Вообще не могу логику как поступать то что циклом понятно но вот я перебрал массив к примеру так пусть искомая строка хранится здесь $search `foreach($myArray as $value){if(if( $value[ "class"] === $search) {/*а вот дальше что*/})` понятно что надо ввести переименую куда все сохранить пусть будет $foundArray;  но вот что делать не понимаю

Comment: if( $value[ "class"] === $search) {
return $value;
}

Comment: @Oboroten да походу вот так надо f( $value[ "class"] === $search) { $foundArray = $value;break; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете сделать вот так пройдя по циклу в массиве.

```
<?php
    foreach($arr as $key => $val){
        // Какая то логика
        print_r($val);
    }
?>
```

`$arr` здесь ваш массив.
В `$key` будут ключи массива а в `$val` будут ваши подмассивы.

Comment: логику вроде спрашивают вполне конкретную, для имеющегося имени класса, сравнить с `$val['class']` и вернуть `$val` целиком.

Comment: @teran логику вы спросили?

Comment: @teran А если правильнее поняли логику вопроса пожалуйста не кто не мешает вам дать свой ответ.